# Detect whether keyboard has the Globe key on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui, appkit

Recent Apple products have the Globe (︎) key on the keyboard. At the AppKit level, it is actually just a fn key that behaves as `NSEvent.ModifierFlags.function`. But is there any way to know whether the keyboard that the user currently uses has the Globe key or just the fn key?

It seems that the system somehow knows it since the shortcut key display in the menu changes depending on the keyboard. The Globe symbol is shown only when the keyboard actually has the Globe key. Otherwise, it shows "fn".

[image: screenshot of menu with Globe symbol]
[image: screenshot of menu with fn symbol]

But, so far, I have not found a way to detect it programmatically in the AppKit/SwiftUI world. I'd like to implement displaying keyboard shortcuts for those menu commands in my own view.

Comment: I have no way to test this but shouldn't you just continue to setup the keyboard shortcut as if all keyboards have a "function" key and let macOS show the correct symbol in the menu? Or are you trying to do something outside of a menu keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @HangarRash As I mentioned, I want to draw shortcuts in my view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [I/O registry](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/TheRegistry/TheRegistry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000014-TP9) seems to have information about whether a globe key exists　(`"SupportsGlobeKey" = Yes` or `No`).

In my environment (MacBook Pro 2023), `ioreg -rln AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2` gives the following results.
(I don't have a desktop machine, so I can't verify the absence of the Globe key).

```
$ ioreg -rln AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2
+-o AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2  <class AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2, id 0x100000ba5, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 10>
  | {
  |   "LocationID" = 49
  |   "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseDriverV2"
  |   "Keyboard" = {"Elements"=({"VariableSize"=0,"UnitExponent"=0,"IsRelative"=No,"UsagePage"=7,"Max"=1,"IsArray"=No,"Type"=2,"Size"=1,"Min"=0,"Flags"=134217730,"ReportID"=1,"Usage"=224,"ReportCount"=1,"Unit"=0,"Ha$
  |   "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
  |   "CapsLockLanguageSwitch" = No
  |   "HIDServiceSupport" = Yes
*snip*
  |   "KeyboardEnabled" = Yes
  |   "PrimaryUsagePage" = 1
  |   "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard"
  |   "SupportsGlobeKey" = Yes
  |   "SensorProperties" = {}
  |   "ProductID" = 0
*snip*
```

To get I/O registry information programmatically, use `IOKit`.

For example, to get whether a globe key exists, use the following code.

```swift
import IOKit

let entry = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMainPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("AppleHIDKeyboardEventDriverV2"))
if let property = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(entry, "SupportsGlobeKey" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)?.takeRetainedValue() {
  print(property) // => 1
}

IOObjectRelease(entry)
```

Comment: Great! I tested the code on my MacBook Pros with and without the Globe key and it correctly distinguished the difference. I suppose the code can be safely used for apps on the MAS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to detect it using a Private API in `ApplicationServices.HIServices`.

```c
HIS_XPC_GetGlobeKeyAvailability();
```

Although, I need to use only public APIs...